# redirect at a specific time of day to different html pages

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, time

I want a webpage that will redirect to different webpages depending on the time of day.
Is this possible and can some one help me out with this.
for instance,
"@6am go to page 1"
"@11am got to page 2"
"@6pm go to page 3"
"@11pm got to page 4"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `new Date` and redirect based on `.getHours()`

```js
var date=new Date();
if(date.getHours()==15){//3:00pm
  window.location="https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en"
 }
```

Comment: as far as i am aware == is if its equal too. but what if i want it to redirect between specific times to a specific page??

Comment: You can do: if(date.getHours()>15&&date.getHours()<21)

Comment: @Daniel.Gallagher This answer is not a complete solution, it's just to point you in the right direction. You will need a timer (setInterval) to run on each page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot do that exactly at that time, but you could check for current time in some interval using setInterval() function. Something liek this:

```
var redirectHour = 18;
var redirectMinute = 30;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
      var currentDate = new Date();
      if (currentDate.getHours() == redirectHour &&
          currentDate.getMinutes() == redirectMinute)
           window.location.href = "HtmlPage2.html";
}, 60000);
```

First parameter of setInterval() is anonymous function where you hand the code you want to run, second parameter is interval in which you want to run function again(in milliseconds). I have set it to 60 000 which is every minute. Change redirectHour and redirectMinute variables to the time you want the page to be redirected.